# How to exclude files from zip by exact path?

Tags: zip

I have two files in the directory:

```
a/b/FFF/d/e.txt
x/y/d/d/FFF/f.txt
```

Now, I want to zip the entire directory, excluding the files that match `*/*/FFF/**` pattern. Thus, the first file should be excluded, while the second one should get into the archive. I'm doing this:

```
$ zip -qq -x '*/*/FFF/*' -r foo.zip .
```

Both files are excluded (because `FFF` is found in their paths, I believe):

```
$ unzip -l foo.zip
Archive:  foo.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  10-24-2023 14:51   a/
        0  10-24-2023 14:51   a/b/
        0  10-24-2023 14:51   x/
        0  10-24-2023 14:51   x/y/
        0  10-24-2023 14:51   x/y/d/
        0  10-24-2023 14:51   x/y/d/d/
---------                     -------
        0                     6 files
```

What's wrong with my exclusion pattern?

By the way:

```
$ zip --version
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you don't have `pcregrep` installed, you can install it on macOS using Homebrew with the following command:

```
brew install pcre
```

Once `pcregrep` is installed, you can modify your script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use find to list all files, and pcregrep to exclude those matching the regex pattern
find . -type f | pcregrep -v '^\.\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/FFF\/' > include.lst

# Use zip with the -@ option to read the list of files from include.lst
zip -qq -@ foo.zip < include.lst

# Optionally, remove the include.lst file if you no longer need it
rm include.lst
```

1. The `find` command lists all files in the current directory and its subdirectories.
2. The `pcregrep` command filters out the files that match the regex pattern `^\.\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/FFF\/`, which corresponds to your original glob pattern `*/*/FFF/*`.
3. The `zip` command reads the list of files from `include.lst` and creates the archive `foo.zip`.
4. Optionally, the `rm` command removes the `include.lst` file if you no longer need it.

Save this script to a file, make it executable with `chmod +x script.sh`, and run it with `./script.sh` to create your zip archive.

Comment: I'm getting a single dot when I run `find . -type f ! -path "*/*/FFF/*" -print0`. Are you sure it should work?

Comment: First, run find . -type f to list all files in the current directory and subdirectories. This will help us understand if find is working as expected.

If the above command lists all files, then try running find . -type f ! -path "*/*/FFF/*" to see if the exclusion pattern works as intended.

Remember, the pattern in find is relative to the starting directory (which is . in this case). Make sure your directory structure actually matches what you expect.

If you find that find is working as expected but zip is not, try running them separately to isolate the issue.

Comment: Apparently, `find . -type f -path '*/*/FFF/*'` prints both files. Maybe this is because it's not a GNU version of `find`? I'm on macOS.

Comment: I installed `gfind` (GNU find) and it also finds both files with `-path '*/*/FFF/*'`

Comment: The issue is with the pattern `*/*/FFF/*`. It's too broad. Use a more specific `find` pattern like this:

`find . -type f ! -path "./[^/]*/[^/]*/FFF/*" -print0 | zip -qq -@ -r foo.zip` 

This ensures `FFF` is specifically the third-level directory.

Comment: The condition `-path "./[^/]*/[^/]*/FFF/*"` doesn't work either, but `-path "./[^/]/[^/]/FFF/*"` works (however, only with one-letter directory names).

Comment: I edited the answer, hope it helps you